# An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends

Tags: c#, asp.net

i 'm working with update panel. here i have to dynamically enable regular expression validator when some condition matched with drop down value selection.

here is my design :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel20" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_Search" runat="server" Width="100px" DefaultButton="btnsearch">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel15" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Column_List" runat="server" 
AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="120px" ValidationGroup="Search" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Column</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>

<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDL_Column_List" 
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" CssClass="input" 
ValidationGroup="Search"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator5" runat="server" 
                    ValidationGroup="Search" 
SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="txtsearch" 
                    ValidationExpression="^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$" 
                    Display="None" Enabled="False"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender20" runat="server" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator5" WarningIconImageUrl="~/images/Warning.gif" CloseImageUrl="~/images/close.gif" >
</ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
</td>
<td><asp:Button ID="btnsearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="button" 
onclick="btnsearch_Click" ValidationGroup="Search"/></td>
</tr></table>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and here is how i enabled regular expression validator based on drop down list selection.

```
 protected void DDL_Column_List_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DDL_Column_List.SelectedItem.Value.Equals("19"))
        {
            RegularExpressionValidator5.Enabled = true;
            RegularExpressionValidator5.ErrorMessage = "Register date format should be like: DD/MM/yyyy";
            UpdatePanel20.Update();
            MPE.Show();
        }
    }
```

how ever when this page loads then one run time error occurs like:

```
Server Error in '/CRM' Application.

An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: An extender can't be in a different UpdatePanel than the control it extends.]
   System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.RegisterWithScriptManager() +443813
   System.Web.UI.ExtenderControl.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +19
   AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +36
   AjaxControlToolkit.ValidatorCalloutExtender.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +124
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

what am i wrong here..
please help me...

Comment: Are you having any other updte panels or can you post your complete aspx page?

Comment: it may be a bit OT, but why disabling the validator, and why putting the errormessage in the codebehind?

Anyway I think that the problem is the  `<ajaxtoolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>`, because if you remove it it works (after adding the ScriptManager obvi).

Comment: @Jameem - ya i have 4 update panel in modal popup extender.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the part of code you have pasted..I copied it and checked it ..It doesn't give any errors in my case..

Comment: if something wrong with design part how can i know it.